# FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made a simple meal recipe app.
It is debugged and runs correctly, but when I click on the drawer on the top left, this popup on the VScode window is shown below:
[image: screenshot]

here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meals_recipes/screens/filters_screen.dart';

class MainDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget buildListTile(String title, IconData icon, Function tapHandler) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(
        icon,
        size: 24,
      ),
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontSize: 22),
      ),
      onTap: tapHandler(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            child: Text(
              'Cooking Up!',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          buildListTile('Meals', Icons.restaurant, () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
          }),
          buildListTile('Filters', Icons.filter, () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(FiltersScreen.routeName);
          }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please help me out.
other sections of the app work.
just when I click on the hamburger menu drawer, it will hang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened in the code is that `tapHandler()` will be instantly called in the process of building the widget, so the callback that contains the navigation method will be called during the build.

---

You can fix it by doing either one of these:

**Option 1**

Change the parameter type from `Function` to `void Function()` to match the required type for the `onTap` property:

```dart
Widget buildListTile(String title, IconData icon, void Function() tapHandler) {
  // ...
}
```

and use `tapHandler` like this:

```dart
ListTile(
  // ...
  onTap: tapHandler,
)
```

**Option 2**

Keep the parameter type as `Function`, but call the `tapHander` inside an anonymous function:

```dart
onTap: () => tapHandler(),
```

Comment: yes, but when I remove (), then I got this error:

Comment: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
Function tapHandler
Type: Function

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can choose either option, I recommend the first one